# Targeting an iFrame once with jQuery

Tags: jquery, selector, frame, targeting

I have a series of frames (4) which are used in a page to create loading of dynamic content through Ajax calls.

In each of these frames I target parent level elements and update them with there respective content e.g.

```
$("#loadingGrid1",top.document).show();
$("#frameSkills",top.document).hide();
```

In jQuery is there a way to instead of targeting specific elements on the parent page multiple times, simply target the page once into a variable e.g.

```
var parentPage=$('#frameSkills',top.document);
```

And then use this variable to apply content like `$(parentPage > #loadingGrid1).hide()`

Hope I've explained what I'm after enough. Basically, I'm having to call "top.document" in every jQuery selector I make and it seems like a waste of energy.

Answer (score 0):

A Jquery object can be used as a context just like a DOM node.

```
var parentPage = $('#frameSkills',top.document);
$("#myselector", parentPage).dostuff();
```

Or you can use the `find` function:

```
parentPage.find("#myselector").dostuff();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [Delegates?](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems cleanest to me:

```
var page = $(top.document); //Define once
page.find("#loadingGrid1").show();
page.find("#frameSkills").hide();
```

When you call `$(selector, context)` you're (in all cases like this anyway) calling `context.find(selector)` inside anyway...might as well make it easy to read/write/chain as you go.